# Is targeted antimicrobial peptide mouthwash currently available anywhere (including experimentally)?

Tags: dentistry, bacteria

For reference:
http://newsroom.ucla.edu/releases/ucla-scientists-explain-mechanism-that-makes-their-mouthwash-so-effective-against-tooth-decay

Antimicrobial peptides as mouthwash were first invented in 2011 at UCLA according to this article. There was a brief burst of news/media attention around them in 2015 and then nothing. What happened to them? Are these mouthwashes available anywhere (including outside the U.S. or in experiments/clinical trials) and where can I get them?

Several searches for where to buy them turned up nothing.

Extra credit question: could this approach be used as a substitute for antibiotics in certain applications or deployed against bacteria that are dangerously resistant to regular antibiotics?

Answer (score 1):

That trial was from Colgate Palmolive and it doesn't appear to have lead to a commercial product yet.  The approach seems flawed anyway as you'll just create a selection pressure to develop resistance.

More promising alternatives are available in the form of probiotics.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5688201/